# factoring numbers in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ into primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

How do I factor, say, 2 + 3$\sqrt{2}$ into primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$?
I know that primes are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and that units are of the form $\pm(1\pm\sqrt{2})^n$. How are primes and units related, if at all?

I understand that all primes of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ are obtained by factoring rational primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. I'm just not sure how to approach this problem.. Any help or hints would be much appreciated!

(Edit) Here is what I have so far:

N(2+3$\sqrt{2}$)=-14=-2*7

7=-1 mod(8), so it is reducible. 7=(3+$\sqrt{2}$)(3-$\sqrt{2}$) and 2=$\sqrt{2}^2$.
So, 3+$\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are irreducible.

(3+$\sqrt{2}$)*$\sqrt{2}$=2+3$\sqrt{2}$

Does this mean that the prime factors are (3+$\sqrt{2}$) and $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Not all primes are irreducible in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt2]$; the condition is that $p\equiv 3,5\mod 8$.

Comment: One useful first step (often) is to calculate the norm, in this case $-14$. Since norm of a product is the product of the norms, that restricts the search considerably.